images are not displayed Next.js when i using funtion Image in import Image
Good day!
I have such a problem. I am writing the Next + TypeScript application.
is my problem
GET / 200 in 174ms
GET /assets/icons/logo-full.svg 404 in 95ms
this is my code
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    // <h1 className="text-white text-3xl underline">Home </h1>
    //<Button>Click me</Button>
    <div className="flex h-screen max-h-screen">
      <section className="remove-scrollbar container my-auto">
        <div className="sub-container max-w-[496px]">
          <Image
          
          src={"/assets/icons/logo-full.svg"}
         // src="@/public/assets/icons/logo-full.svg"
         
          height={1000}
          width={1000}
          alt="patient"
          className="mb-12 h10 w-fit"
          priority
          />
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  )
  
}


I using chat gpt and using  stackoverflow

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
